# Create a variable to count from 1 to n in AnyLogic

Tags: variables, parameters, count, anylogic

I am looking to add a variable to count from 1 to 217 every hour in AnyLogic, in order to use as a choice condition to set a parameters row reference.

I am assuming I either need to use an event or a state chart however I am really struggling with the exact and cannot find anything online.

If you have any tips please let me know, any help would be appreciated

Thank you,
Tash

Answer (score 0):

A state machine isn't necessary in this case as this can be achieve using a calculation or a timed event. AnyLogic has `time()` function which returns time since model start as a *double* in model time units of measurements.

For example: if model time units is *seconds* and it has been running for 2hr 2min 10sec then `time(SECOND)` will return `7330.0` (it is always a *double* value). 1/217th of an hour corresponds to about `3600/217 = 16.58` seconds. Also, java has a handy function `Math.floor()` which rounds down a *double* value, so `Math.floor(8.37) = 8.0`.

Assembling it all together:

```java
   // how many full hours have elapsed from the start of the model
   double fullHrsFromStart = Math.floor(time(HOUR));
   // how many seconds have elapsed in the current model hour
   double secondsInCurrentHour = time(SECOND) - fullHrsFromStart * 3600.0;
   // how many full 16.58 (1/217th of an hour) intervals have elapsed
   int fullIntervals = (int)(secondsInCurrentHour / 16.58);
```

This can be packaged into a function and called any time and it is pretty fast.

**Alternatively**: an `Event` can be created which increments some `count` by 1 every 16.58 seconds and ten resets it back to 0 when the count reaches 217.